# woff2, woff and ttf files not loaded and gave 400 error

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015, webpack

Why woff2, woff and ttf files are not loaded, however they are exist in "assets" folder? Please suggest!

[image]

Comment: your path seems to be `/css/assets/..` and woff files seems to be in `assets`, may be that is the issue.

Comment: Thanks Madhu, this is the issue actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that those mime types aren't set for your IISExpress instance.
Answer originally found [here](http://www.chambaud.com/2013/07/09/iis-express-adding-mime-types/).

Answer 1: This will fix the error for all sites that create that have these file types as a part of their solution and are being run out of IISExpress.

Quoted in part:

Open `ApplicationHost.config` located in `C:\Users\<user>\Documents\IISExpress\config`

Locate `staticContent` section and append the following lines before the closing tag:
   
`<mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
<mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
<mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/octet-stream />`

Answer 1: This will fix the error for that particular site, but any others that you create that have these file types as a part of their solution and are being run out of IISExpress will encounter this same issue.

Update the `Web.config` for your project.
Add
   
`<mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
<mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
<mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/octet-stream />`
in the `staticContent` section in `system.webServer` in `configuration`.

This should get those annoying errors to go away!

Comment: How could I do it if I am using Angular-cli

Comment: it worked like charm! @indra257create your build and add a web.config at root level with given answer.