# Issue loading woff and woff2 in aurelia project

Tags: webpack, aurelia

I am trying to load custom fonts used by materialize css in my aurelia project. When it is published on web server, I see 404 not found error for woff fonts. These fonts are served from `dist` folder.

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

I am using default `webpack` configuration to generate these fonts. When the aurelia project is built, it exports all the fonts in to `dist` folder. If I understand it correct based on below screenshot, It should be served from root path. I am not sure if aurelia looks for font files in dist when request at the root path.

Here is the webpack configuration:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const project = require('./aurelia_project/aurelia.json');
const { AureliaPlugin, ModuleDependenciesPlugin } = require('aurelia-webpack-plugin');
const { optimize: { CommonsChunkPlugin, UglifyJsPlugin }, ProvidePlugin } = require('webpack');
const { TsConfigPathsPlugin, CheckerPlugin } = require('awesome-typescript-loader');

// config helpers:
const ensureArray = (config) => config && (Array.isArray(config) ? config : [config]) || [];
const when = (condition, config, negativeConfig) =>
    condition ? ensureArray(config) : ensureArray(negativeConfig);

// primary config:
const title = 'Aurelia Navigation Skeleton';
const outDir = path.resolve(__dirname, project.platform.output);
const srcDir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');
const nodeModulesDir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules');
const baseUrl = '/';

const cssRules = [
    { loader: 'css-loader' },
];

module.exports = ({ production, server, extractCss, coverage } = {}) => ({
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
        modules: [srcDir, 'node_modules'],
    },
    entry: {
        app: ['aurelia-bootstrapper'],
        vendor: [
            'bluebird', 'whatwg-fetch'
        ],
    },
    output: {
        path: outDir,
        publicPath: baseUrl,
        filename: production ? '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.js' : '[name].[hash].bundle.js',
        sourceMapFilename: production ? '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.map' : '[name].[hash].bundle.map',
        chunkFilename: production ? '[name].[chunkhash].chunk.js' : '[name].[hash].chunk.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: outDir,
        // serve index.html for all 404 (required for push-state)
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
    devtool: production ? 'nosources-source-map' : 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            // CSS required in JS/TS files should use the style-loader that auto-injects it into the website
            // only when the issuer is a .js/.ts file, so the loaders are not applied inside html templates
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                issuer: [{ not: [{ test: /\.html$/i }] }],
                use: extractCss ? ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: cssRules
                }) : ['style-loader', ...cssRules],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                issuer: [{ test: /\.html$/i }],
                // CSS required in templates cannot be extracted safely
                // because Aurelia would try to require it again in runtime
                use: cssRules
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
                issuer: /\.[tj]s$/i
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
                issuer: /\.html?$/i
            },
            { test: /\.html$/i, loader: 'html-loader' },
            { test: /\.ts$/i, loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader', exclude: nodeModulesDir },
            { test: /\.json$/i, loader: 'json-loader' },
            // use Bluebird as the global Promise implementation:
            { test: /[\/\\]node_modules[\/\\]bluebird[\/\\].+\.js$/, loader: 'expose-loader?Promise' },
            // embed small images and fonts as Data Urls and larger ones as files:
            { test: /\.(png|gif|jpg|cur)$/i, loader: 'url-loader', options: { limit: 8192 } },
            { test: /\.woff2(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/i, loader: 'url-loader', options: { limit: 10000, mimetype: 'application/font-woff2' } },
            { test: /\.woff(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/i, loader: 'url-loader', options: { limit: 10000, mimetype: 'application/font-woff' } },
            // load these fonts normally, as files:
            { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|otf)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/i, loader: 'file-loader' },
            ...when(coverage, {
                test: /\.[jt]s$/i, loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter-loader',
                include: srcDir, exclude: [/\.{spec,test}\.[jt]s$/i],
                enforce: 'post', options: { esModules: true },
            })
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new AureliaPlugin(),
        new ProvidePlugin({
            'Promise': 'bluebird',
            '$': 'jquery',
            'jQuery': 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
        }),
        new ModuleDependenciesPlugin({
            'aurelia-testing': ['./compile-spy', './view-spy']
        }),
        new TsConfigPathsPlugin(),
        new CheckerPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'index.ejs',
            minify: production ? {
                removeComments: true,
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                collapseInlineTagWhitespace: true,
                collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                minifyCSS: true,
                minifyJS: true,
                removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
                removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
                ignoreCustomFragments: [/\${.*?}/g]
            } : undefined,
            metadata: {
                // available in index.ejs //
                title, server, baseUrl
            }
        }),
        ...when(extractCss, new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: production ? '[contenthash].css' : '[id].css',
            allChunks: true
        })),
        ...when(production, new CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ['common']
        })),
        ...when(production, new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            { from: 'static/favicon.ico', to: 'favicon.ico' }
        ])),
        ...when(production, new UglifyJsPlugin({
            sourceMap: true
        }))
    ]
});
```

Comment: If you can see the files in the dist folder then you have to configure your server to serve those files properly. In iis you can do it like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/28955302/7600742

Comment: Also for IISExpress: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41810137/woff2-woff-and-ttf-files-not-loaded-and-gave-400-error/41810316#41810316