# woff-files from library not ending up in dist-folder

Tags: angular, angular-library, bootstrap-icons

I've built an angular component library in which I use [bootstrap-icons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-icons). In the same [NX workspace](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap) there's an application where I'm [using this component](https://bootstrap.mintplayer.com/basic/timepicker), and this works fine:

[image: angular library woff files end up in application dist]

The woff-files from bootstrap-icons end up in the application dist-folder. However, when I create a seperate application ([example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-tearjp?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=package.json,src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)), where I use this component, it seems that the woff-files from `bootstrap-icons` don't end up in the dist-folder.

[image: New project its dist-folder]

[image: ng-bootstrap inside the node_modules folder]

[image: bootstrap-icons inside the node_modules folder)]

This is how I reference bootstrap-icons from my angular library:

[image]

I'm able to [specify that assets should be shipped](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/ng-package.json#L10) inside my node-module, however in this case I have to refer to assets from another node-module...

### Attempts

- Just include the folder into the applications assets

[image: Just include the folder into the applications assets]

- Modify the library `ng-package.json` to copy over files from the node_modules to the library output:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Since the files don't even end up in the dist-folder, I hasn't got anything to do with [the webserver configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41810137/woff2-woff-and-ttf-files-not-loaded-and-gave-400-error)

Why are these files not ending up in my dist-folder? How can I make this work as expected?

### EDIT

I just tried an example from the [official git repository](https://github.com/nrwl/nx-examples/blob/master/apps/products/project.json#L24-L28) like this:

project.json

```
{
  ...,
  "targets": {
    "build": {
      ...,
      "assets": [{
        "glob": "**/*",
        "input": "libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/src/assets/**",
        "output": "assets"
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work. I tried all sorts of things by now...